# I want to show $E(X)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X\ge n)$

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value

Let $X:\Omega \to \mathbb N$ be a random variable on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal B,P)$ .show that $$E(X)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X\ge n).$$

my definition from $E(X)$ is equal
$$E(X)=\int_\Omega X \, dP.$$

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you want to add that $X\geq 0$ ... no?

Comment: @Stat:no, $P(X \ge 0) = 1$. $X$ is natural. Consider $X$ always equal to 2. $E(X) = 2 = P(X\ge 1) + P(X\ge 2)$.

Comment: oops, didn't see $N$!

Comment: The statement is (slightly) incorrect: because $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$, the summation must begin at $0$ instead of $1$.

Comment: @whuber No, the sum must start at $n=1$ (try the case when $P[X=42]=1$).

Comment: @Did Thank you for pointing that out!  Obviously I did not think this through with sufficient care.  I had been misreading the inequalities in the sum as strict inequalities, conforming with the convention that the survival function is defined by strict inequalities.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Definition of $E(X)$ for discrete $X$ is $E(X) = \sum_i x_i \cdot P(X = x_i)$.

$$P( X \ge i ) = P( X = i ) + P( X = i + 1 ) + \cdots$$

So

\begin{align}
& \sum_i P( X \ge i ) = P( X \ge 1 ) + P( X \ge 2 ) + \cdots \\[8pt]
= {} & P( X = 1 ) + P( X = 2 ) + P( X = 3 ) + \cdots + P(X = 2 ) + P( X = 3 ) + \cdots
\end{align}

(we rearange the terms in the last expression)

\begin{align}
& = 1 \cdot P( X = 1 ) + 2 \cdot P( X = 2 ) + 3 \cdot P( X = 3 ) + \cdots \\[8pt]
& = \sum_i i \cdot P( X = i )
\end{align}

q.e.d.

Comment: You are supposed to provide helpful hints for the self-study tags not the full answer. It is better not to solve their assignments :)

Comment: Don't you need to explain why can you re-order the sum? that would be important if you are looking for a rigourous demonstration.

Comment: @January.in the question $X$ is random variable dont mention $X$ is discrete or Continuous.

Comment: Pual, yes you did indicate $X$ is discrete in the very first line: "discrete" (in its broadest possible sense) means there is a countable subset of the variable's range for which it has probability $1$; and because $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, your $X$ must be discrete.

Comment: @whuber.I agree and got it .and thank you from all.

Answer (score 12):

I like January's answer. May I suggest a way to write down the series so that the eye catches the rearrangement more easily (this is the way I like to write it on the blackboard)?
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X\geq k) &=& \quad P(X\geq 1) \quad=\quad P(X=1)&+&P(X=2)&+&P(X=3) &+& \;\dots\\
&+& \quad P(X\geq 2) &+& P(X=2) &+&P(X=3)&+& \;\dots \\ \\
&+& \quad P(X\geq 3) && &+& P(X=3)&+& \;\dots \\ \\
&+& \quad\quad\;\; \dots && &&&+& \;\dots\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
(The rearrangement is mathematically sound because this is a [series of positive terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions).)

Comment: Do you assume X is discrete?

Comment: @BCLC, the formula works only when X can take positive integers. Indeed, for, say, standard uniform distribution it gives 1 whereas the answer is 1/2. Or, even in discrete case let's consider two point distribution $P(X = 1/4) = P(X = 1/2) = 1/2$: the formula gives 0, whereas mean value is 3/8.

Answer (score 5):

I think the standard way of doing this is by writing

$$X =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbf{1}(X\ge n)$$

$$E(X) =E\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbf{1}(X\ge n)\right)$$

and then reverse order of expectation and sum (by Tonelli's theorem)

Comment: Interesting. Is it correct to say that this does NOT assume $X$ is discrete? :O

Comment: @BCLC The first line is only true if X is a natural number, so it is not correct....

Answer (score 2):

One of the other excellent answers here (from [seanv507](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/27556/seanv507)) has noted that this expectation rule actually follows from a stronger result that expresses the underlying random variable as an infinite sum of indicator variables.  It is possible to prove a more general result, and this can be used to get the expectation rule in the question.  If $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ (so its support is no wider than the natural numbers) then it can be shown (proof below) that:

$$X = \sum_{n=1}^{\max(X,m)} \mathbb{I}(X \geqslant n)
\quad \quad \quad
\text{for all } m \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Taking $m \rightarrow \infty$ then gives the useful result:

$$X = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{I}(X \geqslant n).$$

It is worth noting that this result is stronger than the expectation rule in the question, since it gives a decomposition for the underlying random variable, and not just its moment.  As noted in the other answer, taking expectations of both sides of this equation, and applying Tonelli's theorem (to swap the order of the sum and expectation operators), gives the expectation rule in the question.  This is a standard expectation rule that is used when dealing with non-negative random variables.

---

The above result can be proved fairly simply.  Begin by observing that:

$$X = \underbrace{1+1+ \cdots +1}_{ X \text{ times}} + \underbrace{0+0+ \cdots +0}_{ \text{countable times}}.$$

For any $m \in \mathbb{N}$ we therefore have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
X &= \underbrace{1+1+ \cdots +1}_{ X \text{ times}} + \underbrace{0+0+ \cdots +0}_{ \max(0,m-X) \text{ times}} \\[6pt] 
&= \sum_{n=1}^X \mathbb{I}(X \geqslant n) + \sum_{n=1}^{\max(0,m-X)} \mathbb{I}(X \geqslant X+ n) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{n=1}^X \mathbb{I}(X \geqslant n) + \sum_{n=X+1}^{\max(X,m)} \mathbb{I}(X \geqslant n) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\max(X,m)} \mathbb{I}(X \geqslant n) . \\[6pt] 
\end{aligned} \end{equation}.$$